# VSCode: how to interrupt a running Python test?

Tags: python, testing, visual-studio-code, pytest

I'm using VSCode Test Explorer to run my Python unit tests. There was a bug in my code and my tested method never finishes.

How do I interrupt my test? I can't find how to do it using the GUI. I had to close VSCode to interrupt it.

I'm using pytest framework.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Silly me, here is the *Stop button* at the top right of the the Testing tab:

[image: Test stop button]

Comment: Not silly, took me a long time to find it as well. For future readers, the stop button is at the top of the "testing" tab, accessed by click the Erlenmeyer flask icon.

Comment: But... what if you run a single test individually? Then the button at the top is the run button still, but the individual test is the blue "..." icon. Not sure there is a stop in this case.

Comment: It works in debugging mode, but otherwise it keeps running in the background (see "Python Test Log" output window)

Comment: I'm SILLY toooooo. Thanks!

Comment: "Run instance cancelled" does not send any signal to the running test... it does not interrupt a running test.

Comment: Thanks on behalf of all silly people in the world. There are a lot of us

Answer (score 1):

most test runners have a max-running-time setting

if a test takes longer it will be aborted and flagged as failed

From the pytest doc pages:

Create a file: `pytest.ini`

```ini
[pytest]
faulthandler_timeout=5
```