# How to terminate a long-running Python unittest in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

VSCode 1.71.0 on macOS 12.5.1 (Apple M1)

Python 3.10.6 in venv

I have a unittest setup, executed from within VSCode, which is running for much longer than it should (due to an inefficient algorithm in my code at present). The only way I can find to terminate the long-running task is to SIGTERM it thru `top`. The test is displayed as running in the Test Explorer, but it has no further control over the process

I'm looking for how I can do this via VSCode if possible. I have tried the following options:

- Nothing available by right-click in the Test Explorer, just the start / debug options.
- Ctrl-C in the Python test log output or in the Python output windows does nothing
- Running as a debug session, with no breakpoints does at least offer me a stop button. Is this my best option, even though it brings the overhead of a debug session?

My fallback option is to run the tests from the CLI:

`python -m unittest tests.test_file.TestMethods.test_1`

where I can ctrl-c, but I'd like to be able to have the same control in the Test Explorer.

Comment: you could set a `max-time-for-test`, the test runner will kill the current test if it takes more time

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that. But I'm about to make a right fool of myself by self-answering myself! While looking into how to do that with unittest I noticed another post which showed me what I'd been missing all along. A stop button at the top of the test explorer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode: how to interrupt a running Python test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71803409/vscode-how-to-interrupt-a-running-python-test)

Comment: I already found the answer to the issue, as you'd see in the accepted answer I posted myself. Indeed, I quote your own answer when you had a similar issue. Maybe read a bit further...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems my OP was a bit of a duplicate and I have missed the obvious. Thx to @rioV8 for the clue.

[An answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71803409/vscode-how-to-interrupt-a-running-python-test) shows the stop button at the top of the Test Explorer that I had missed.

[image]